# How to update in indexeddb instead of override all the data?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I really enjoyed this very simple use of indexeddb, but I was trying to figure out how to do update.

I have seen that .put is suppose to work for this, but when I have tried this, it would just override all the data for id 12345.  What am I missing?

This is what I was using below:

store.put({id: 12345, name: {first: "John", last: "Doe"}, age: 42});

store.put({id: 12345, name: {first: "somethingelse"}, age: 42});

Full code:

```
      var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

      // Open (or create) the database
      var open = indexedDB.open("MyDatabase", 1);

      // Create the schema
      open.onupgradeneeded = function() {
          var db = open.result;
          var store = db.createObjectStore("MyObjectStore", {keyPath: "id"});
          var index = store.createIndex("NameIndex", ["name.last", "name.first"]);
      };

      open.onsuccess = function() {
          // Start a new transaction
          var db = open.result;
          var tx = db.transaction("MyObjectStore", "readwrite");
          var store = tx.objectStore("MyObjectStore");
          var index = store.index("NameIndex");

          // Add some data
          store.put({id: 12345, name: {first: "John", last: "Doe"}, age: 42});
          store.put({id: 12345, name: {first: "somethingelse"}, age: 42});

          // Query the data
          var custInfo = store.get(12345);

          custInfo.onsuccess = function() {
              alert("ID " + custInfo.result.id + " age " +custInfo.result.age + " name " + custInfo.result.name.first+ custInfo.result.name.last);  // => "John"
              // alert(getJohn.result.name.first);  // => "John"
          };

          // Close the db when the transaction is done
          tx.oncomplete = function() {
              db.close();
          };
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then I would point out that calling put is not equivalent to SQL update. You cannot replace only some properties of an object in an object store using a single request. When putting a new object into a store, if another object with the same keypath (id) already exists, that existing object will be replaced, entirely. indexedDB does not modify the existing object in the store, a property at a time, instead it completely replaces the old object with a new object.

If you want to only replace some properties of an object, use two requests. One request to get the existing object in the store, and a second request to store the modified object. In between the get and put, make changes to the object.

Something like this, pseudocode:

```
function updateSomeProps(db, id) {
  var tx = db.transaction(...);
  tx.oncomplete = _ => {
    console.log('finished updating object with id', id);
  };

  var store = tx.objectStore(...);
  var getRequest = store.get(id);
  getRequest.onsuccess = _ => {
     var obj = getRequest.result;
     if(!obj) {
       console.log('no matching object for id, canceling update', id);
       return;
     }

     console.log('loaded object to modify', obj);

     // make some changes to the properties of the object loaded 
     // in memory
     obj.age = 42;
     obj.firstname = 'asdf';
     delete obj.lastname;

     // now store the new object in place of the old object
     console.log('storing new object in place of old', obj);
     store.put(obj);
  };
}

function connectAndChangeStuff(id) {
  var openRequest = indexedDB.open(...);
  openRequest.onsuccess = _ => {
    var db = openRequest.result;
    updateSomeProps(db, 12345);
    db.close(); // optional
  };
}
```

Comment: So get the information from memory, then put it back in.  I can do that, it just will be a long row.  At least it is reliable compared to hidden html fields. :)

Comment: Hello Josh, thanks alot for that info regarding updates.  To be honest it's quite disappointing that indexeddb does not have that ability, besides storage size, it would have been the second most important reason I had for migrating from localstorage to indexeddb (partial record updates).

Comment: This behavior forces the dev to consider idb store design carefully. Imagine wanting to update a single prop with a true/false on 50 objs, each obs has other props with very large strings. You have to read those large objs out, update your true/false prop and write them back. This is not efficient.